# Opening text messaging app with attachment

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to start an Intent from a Unity app that will launch the text messaging app with an attachment.

I have been able to open the text messaging app but the attachment does not load properly, throwing the following exception:

> 'Could not determine type of
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.torpedoesaway.memematch/files/Gifit2MemeFiles/gifit2meme-2019-09-7-09-39-54.gif
>   java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed:
>   status = 0x80000000'

Note that I have also tried loading other images, such as pngs and jpgs, all throwing the same error.

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + recipient));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);

if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
   activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I tried playing around with the intent action as well as the `setData`/`setType` calls and in one instance I am able to open the chooser, select the messaging app and then the attachment is loaded properly. However, I want to open the text messaging app directly with the attachment working.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:

How I'm making the call from Unity:

```
AndroidJavaClass Uri = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uri = Uri.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", path);

        unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        pluginClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.torpedosaway.giftomessage.Gif2Message");
        pluginClass.Call(
            "ComposeMmsMessage",
            "53876045",
            "message",
            uri,
            unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"));
```

Comment: did you test it on emulator? looks you should try it with device.

Comment: I obviously tested this on device...

Comment: umm, well, will look into it

Comment: Thanks :) I should note that I also tried "sms:", "mms:" and "mmsto:", with no change in behavior

Comment: This is java code, right? where is the integration with unity app or how are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, this is java code. I didn't add the unity side since the call seems to be made correctly, but I will add it regardless.

Comment: intent.setType("image/gif") forces the context chooser to open? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: intent.setType("image/gif") opens chooser and the sms app is not even one of the options.

Comment: and why would one want to attach a GIF to a [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) ??

Comment: I also tried with 'mms://' and 'mmsto://' with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just before you call **startActivity(intent);**

Add these lines:

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Then call

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you explain why and how this code fixes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer to your question (Note the additional line in the code and the conversion of `ACTION_SENDTO` to `ACTION_SEND`) -

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment, long phoneNumber) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
     intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); // For the text that you want to send
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment); // For the atachment, which be a photo, video, file, etc. If you are using Firebase, you might want to take a look at the official Firebase Docs Page on this topic - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/start
     if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

Here is the android mainfest -

```
<activity ...>
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <data android:type="text/plain" />
         <data android:type="image/*" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this helps!!

Source - https://developer.android.com/

Comment: That is where I got my own code from. I tested that version first and it opens a chooser that only shows me messenger and viber as options on my device.

Comment: Also, isn't the intent-filter used if I wanted my own app to be able to response to that intent? That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The intent filter is also used for `SENDTO` or `SEND` type events. Another thing is that after a quick search, I found that the error you encountered is usually due to lack of permissions. It may also be because of the inappropriate loading of an image. I'm sorry I could not be of much help.

Comment: I would agree with you, would it not work correctly when going through the chooser. But I think if it was a permissions issue or wrong file, etc. it wouldn't load it correctly when going through the chooser. This is why I'm kinda baffled by it :/ Thank you for trying thou!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));
    intent.setType("image/gif");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send"));
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn´t work for me using Unity!

Comment: This is one of the combinations I have already tried, as mentioned in the question. Doesn't work either.